# Removing elements from an array non-destructively

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-1.9

Given an array `arr` and an object `v`, I want a copy of `arr` without the elements equal to `v`.

I found these two solutions:

```
newarr = arr.dup
newarr.delete(v)
```

and

```
newarr = arr.reject {|a| a == v}
```

Is there an easier way to do it?

I wonder whether Ruby already has something like:

```
newarr = arr.without(v)
```

Comment: Note that Ruby 1.9 is no longer supported by the core Ruby team. If it's at all possible, migrate to something in the 2.x series. 2.4.1 is current.

Comment: Simply put, you are asking for a non-destructive version of `delete`.

Comment: @engineersmnky oops, I didn't read the documentation of [`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-delete) carefully and I ignored its return value. You are right.

Comment: `grep_v` may be useful but uses `===` instead of `==` so it's not the same thing.

Comment: @tadman: I would love to. It's not my decision...

Comment: @sagarpandya82 : In my case, === would work equally well, but `grep_v` is not in Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5] - [4]
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

If this is too cumbersome for you too, use:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5].reject(&4.method(:==))
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

Comment: @MarkThomas Let me guess: `Array#-`? :)

Comment: Hint: I'm considering putting it on a list of things to reject in a code review :)

Comment: @MarkThomas yeah, the censorship, we know how it happens when the democracy to use shortcuts suffers under the yoke of the senior dictators!

Comment: It all starts when the proletariat starts using "shortcuts" that are neither shorter to type nor to grok!

Comment: @MarkThomas **Liberty or Death** `.reject(&:==.to_proc.curry(2).call(4))` :)

Comment: I predict we will see more of #2 in the days to come. Another recent answer used something like that--perhaps authored by mudsie as well. The sad fact is that `&4.method(:==)` contains 5 characters more than `{|n|n==4}`.

Comment: ...and an extra set of parens for a total of 7 more!

Comment: @MarkThomas the first set is optional though so can you really count them?

Comment: That is why I have monkeypatched `Object` to alias `method` as `m` in all my projects. Once for all saving 5 chars!

Comment: @engineersmnky they lied about characters count increase last year, I knew that.